# monitoring JVM metrics via snmp using JMX.

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, snmp

We have multiple Web logic and and Tomcat based applications. What are typical solutions  to get a “standard” method for monitoring heap issues, hogging threads, etc for these different java applications with different garbage collection formats.

Typically what I want to do is grab last full Garbage collection and regular Garbage collection entries from these applications and want to grab the initial max values from them.  Make calculations, save data to the for reporting and will generate alert if thresholds met.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks
Bhopali

Answer (score 0):

Why write one when you can use one?

http://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/monitor-tomcat.html?gclid=CN_Z68OCsLACFWkCQAodbi17Uw

Comment: Well this is not just tomcat. We also have Weblogic and other containers.

Comment: I'd still use whatever tools were at hand.  I would never take on the challenge of writing such a thing until all other possibilities were exhausted.